# MSSQL Dynamic SQL for table creation from view fails only when executed through job

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I have a problem with my recurring table creation.
I have a bunch of views that need to be written into tables.

My approach is, that for every view there is, a table should be created and therefore I realized it with dynamic SQL. So that I don't have to touch the job every time I add a view.

My problem is, the code works fine as long as I execute it myself within SSSM.
As soon as I put it in a job and it is executed by schedule or by myself it fails. If I replace the dynamic SQL with the code it produces, the job fails as well. I even put the code into a stored procedure and just executed that from the job and that produced the same result.

The error states that it couldn't convert a nvarchar type into a datetime type. 
I checked every view and ran the code for every view/table singly as well as all at once and there was no error.

Has anyone an idea what's wrong here?

Here is the dynamic SQL code that I use:

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max);

SELECT @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL + ' ', '') + 'IF OBJECT_ID(''' + REPLACE(name, 'qry_', 'tbl_') + ''', ''U'') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(REPLACE(name, 'qry_', 'tbl_')) + ';  SELECT * INTO ' + QUOTENAME(REPLACE(name, 'qry_', 'tbl_')) + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';'
FROM sys.views
WHERE LEFT(name, 4) = 'qry_'

EXEC (@sql);
```

Comment: I'd guess that the problem is the `VIEW`, not the dynamic SQL. Rather than trying to do all your operations in one go, I'd actually suggest using a `CURSOR` here (yes, that's right I recommended a `CURSOR`). Then  add some `PRINT` statements to help debug your SQL. `PRINT` items such as the value of `@SQL` and the name of the `VIEW` you're about use to create a new `TABLE`. You'll the  find the offending `VIEW` and can debug it.

Comment: I executed every view singely and none was the problem. As I said, when I execute the code inside SSSM by myself it works just fine.

Comment: I'm fairly confident that the code you have posted simply cannot fail with the error you have supplied, because all it does is `DROP TABLE` and `SELECT INTO`, neither of which ever involve conversions. You'll have to track down where it *actually* fails. This can be something obscure, like a DDL trigger. It can also involve something like schema mismatches (as in, you're not always talking about the same objects you think you're talking about, depending on the account you log in with).

Comment: Oh wait, I'm overlooking the obvious. :-P The `SELECT` statements you do certainly *can* fail, of course, depending on what's in the views. It is absolutely possible for one user to get different data or different errors from a view, depending on the query plans generated (which in turn also depend on `SET` options, which can also differ between SSMS and other clients). What you should do is log in as a user under which this statement fails, and check every individual `SELECT .. INTO` statement on every individual view for possible failures.

Comment: But if I execute the job via "start job at step" then it runs under my user, right? Also it fails with the job being executed by schedule. I think I can't use that "user".

Comment: No, it does not run as you, it runs as the account SQL Server Agent uses (by default, if not changed, this is a virtual service account, but it often is changed). This is regardless of how you start the job (on demand or scheduled). It's possible to configure another user, in the "advanced" properties of the job step. Logging in "as" SQL Server Agent isn't possible if it's a virtual account, which makes it harder to troubleshoot things. You can use Profiler to trace exactly what statement is failing, and log things like `@@OPTIONS` with `xp_logevent` -- though a dedicated user is easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This SQL is untested, however, this should greatly help you. Notice that I do each execution separately. Firstly, this does (actually) mean that if the dynamic SQL fails that it won't propagate out (this may not be intended, however). I also, though, have added `PRINT` statements so you can inspect the logs and see what was actually done; and what view was failed out. `PRINT @SQL;` is commented out, as (if I recall correctly), the Agent logs can only hold 8000 or 4000 characters, so printing the value of `@SQL` would over bloat it.

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX), @ViewName sysname;

DECLARE qry_views CURSOR FOR
SELECT [name]
FROM sys.views
WHERE [name] LIKE 'qry[_]%'

OPEN qry_views;

FETCH NEXT FROM qry_views
INTO @ViewName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    PRINT 'Creating table from View ' + QUOTENAME(@ViewName);

    SET @SQL = N'IF OBJECT_ID(''' + REPLACE(@ViewName, N'qry_', N'tbl_') + N''', ''U'') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(REPLACE(@ViewName, N'qry_', N'tbl_')) + N';' + NCHAR(10) + 
               N'SELECT *' + NCHAR(10) +
               N'INTO ' + QUOTENAME(REPLACE(@ViewName, N'qry_', N'tbl_')) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@ViewName) + N';';

    --PRINT @SQL;

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

    FETCH NEXT FROM qry_views
    INTO @ViewName;

END

CLOSE qry_views;
DEALLOCATE qry_views;
```

Comment: I now found which view causes the problem most probably. The job itself failed either way but I guess that's because one of the views raised an error in the execution process.

Thanks a lot for that code! I have to learn a lot to fully understand all the commands but I've wanted to do something like this for quite some time. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the job, do you call a stored proc by using date literals, like:

```
exec my_proc @my_param='20180524'
```

? You can't do this. Assing the values to a var first, then use the var:

```
declare @my_value date ='20180524'
exec my_proc @my_param=@my_value
```

Comment: The SP only had the code above in it without any parameters.